# "Users is not a function" -- Discord.JS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm a bit new to Javascript and Discord.JS and was wondering if I could get some help? I keep getting "Users is not a function" in my terminal after trying to run the bot. I'm also wondering if I coded the bot correctly or not. My goal is to have the bot privately message someone at a set time every day.

Thank you.

```
const e = require('express')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const config = require('./config.json')
const privateMessage = require('./private-message')

const cron = require('node-cron');
const express = require('express');

cron.schedule('42 23 * * *', function() {
    console.log('cron is working');
}, {
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "America/New_York"
});

    client.login(config.token).then(() => {
        console.log('The client is ready!');
        var dm = client.users.fetch('749097582227357839');
        if(users && client.users.fetch('749097582227357839'))
            client.users.fetch('749097582227357839').send("hello").then(() => client.destroy());
    
         else 
        console.log("nope");
    
        client.destroy();
    
});


client.login(config.token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make the bot message someone you can do this-

```js
client.users
      .fetch('749097582227357839')
      .then((user) => {
        user.send(`Hello`,);
     });
```

I hope this fixes your problem :D

Comment: I tried that but I got an error that said DiscordjsError: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client. Any ideas? `

Comment: You can check if you are doing anything wrong here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#request-to-use-token-but-token-was-unavailable-to-the-client

Comment: Thank you for giving me the first part of the code to message somebody with your original message. I'm going to ask another question to try to fix the token issue, thank you though.